# javascript closure and scope chain example

Tags: javascript, binding, closures, scope-chain

Can someone explain to me (clearly and concisely) why this code works the way it does? I come from a strongly typed background in Java (6 and 7) where closures don't exist and do not function the way they do in javascript. I think the concepts related to this question are: closures and scope chain.

Here's the example:

```
var myfuncs = function() {
    var funcs = []
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       funcs[i] = function() { console.log(i); }
    }
    return funcs;
}

var allfuncs = myfuncs();
allfuncs.forEach(function(fn) { fn(); });
```

The above example logs 9 (10 times), but the expectation and my own intuition was thinking it would log 0-9.

Why does this work the way it does in Javascript? Closures are very powerful, but I'm trying to grasp the concept once and for good! A slightly modified example produces the right output, but why?

```
var myfuncs = function() {
    var funcs = []
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       funcs[i] = (function(index) { console.log(index); })(i);
    }
    return funcs;
}

var allfuncs = myfuncs();
allfuncs.forEach(function(fn) { fn(); });
```

Closures aren't unique to Javascript, but I want to see why they are powerful in the context of when javascript is actaully written to interface with the browser/dom.

Does anyone have good, practical examples of how we can apply the closure technique when interfacing with the browser/dom?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: It's very simple really: JavaScript only has function scope. I.e. every closures references the same variable `i`. And the variables are evaluated when the functions are called, not when they are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples you have, it is very simple.

In your first example, there is only one variable `i` and everything references that single value.  So.. it prints the number `9` ten times.  Each function captured a *shared* value of `i` that changes.

In the second example you are using a closure. Each function has a private variable called `index` which receives -- and here is the important part -- a **copy** of the value `i`.

So, you get `0` through `9` because there are ten functions, each one with a private `index` variable and each of those `index` variables get a snapshot of `i` **as it existed at the time.**

This, longer form of a closure, may help:

```
function myFactory(index) {
  return function() {
    console.log(index);
  }
}

var myfuncs = function() {
    var funcs = []
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       funcs[i] = myFactory(i);
    }
    return funcs;
}

var allfuncs = myfuncs();
allfuncs.forEach(function(fn) { fn(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Did you mean "var myFactory(index)" instead to be 
"var myFactory = function(index) { ... }"?

Comment: Actually, I meant `function`.  Fixed.  Thanks.